# Identify characters in a series by a line number

Tags: algorithm, combinations, reverse-engineering, series

this is my first time on here. I searched and couldn't find anything relevant. Trying to work something out:

Where a=1, b=2, c=3 ... z=26

If you were to create a series where it goes through every possible outcome of letters and using 1 character length in numerical order, the total possible number of outcomes is 26 (26^1). You easily figure "e" would be on line 5 of the series. "y" would be line 25.

If you set the parameters to a 2 character length, the total number of combinations is 676 (26^2), "aa" would be line 1, "az" would be line 26, "ba" would be line 27, "zz" would be line 676. This is easily calculated, and can be done no matter what the character length is, you will always find what line it would be on in the series.

My question is how do you do it in reverse? Using the same parameters, 1 will obviously be "aa", 31 will be "be". How do you work out with a formula that 676 will be "zz"? 676, based on the parameters set, can only be "zz", it can't be any other set of characters. So there should be a way of calculating this, no matter how long the number is,  as long as you know the parameters of the series.

If length of characters was 10, what characters would be on line 546,879,866, for example?

Is this even doable? Thanks so much in advance

Comment: This should be possible. So what did you tried? Where is your initial logic for simple numbers?

Comment: It is enough to translate 546,879,866 into 26-base number.

Comment: To work out what line number a set of characters would appear on I just used basic math (there's probably a much better way of doing it, just using what I know:

EG: Characters = 1-26, character length = 3 (Total possibilities 26^3 = 17576 / aaa = 1, zzz = 17576)

This set of characters "rug" is line 12019 (r = 18, u = 21, g = 7)
I calculated this by:
(((total characters ^ character length) / total characters) * (r - 1)) + (((total characters ^ (character length - 1) / total characters) * (u - 1)) + g = 12019. Simplified: (((26^3)/26)*(18-1))+(((26^(2))/26)*(21-1))+7=12019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough to translate 546,879,866 into 26-base number. For example in bash:

```
echo 'obase=26 ; 546879866' | bc
 01 20 00 19 03 23 00
```

And if your prefere 10 caracters you should fill the number from the beginning:

```
 00 00 00 01 20 00 19 03 23 00
```

Just note that numeration starts from 0 which is mean a=00, b=01, … z=25.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! I know it was probably very basic, but this just solved a major road bump for me :)